# NSTableCellView & Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to compile an App for Snow Leopard that contains an NSTableCellView reference, even if the window containing the reference to NSTableCellView is never displayed? (IE a different view is displayed if snow leopard is detected)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only if the nib containing the view-based `NSTableView` is never loaded on Snow Leopard. You'd need to use an `NSViewController` and two different nibs, one for Lion and one for Snow Leopard. Use a conditional in the view controller's `init` method to do that:

```
- (id)init
{
     NSString* nibName = NSClassFromString(@"NSTableCellView") ? @"YourLionNibName" : @"YourSnowLeopardNibName";
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
     return self;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks for the help!